# Adapting this Counting Sort algorithm (pseudocode) to sort a sequence of n decimal numbers?

Tags: algorithm, performance, sorting, pseudocode

If I were to present you with this counting sort algorithm: [image]

Would it be possible to adapt this pseudocode for Counting Sort to sort a sequence of decimal numbers?

Like if I was to give you a sequence A of n decimal numbers (1.897, 2.34, 76.9834, 5...) and let's also say these values have at most 4 decimals...would it be possible to modify this Counting Sort to sort the sequence?

In my mind, wouldn't implementing Radix Sort with counting sort be the obvious choice to make this happen...or would this only work for integers?

Comment: You could of course convert the all the values to integers (e.g, `[1.897, 2.34, 76.9834] -> [18970, 23400, 769834]`) and sort those, but my understanding is that "counting sort is an algorithm for sorting a collection of objects according to keys that are small positive integers". [Ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort).

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. You ask how to adapt counting sort, but then you suggest radix sort is a valid solution. If you want a practical sorting algorithm, just use whatever the standard library in your chosen programming language uses. If this is an algorithm question, you need to be more specific about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: If you set out to adapt counting sort to multi-digit sequences, then you should end up with a radix sort, and it can work for decimals if you do it right.  Whether or not that counts as "possible to modify" depends on what you count as a modification.

Comment: The question behind what I'm trying to do is exactly this: "Suppose that memory space is not an issue. How can you adapt Counting Sort (using a simple mod) to sort the sequence A (or n decimal numbers with up to 4 decimals)" - the question itself and it's solvability is language agnostic

Comment: Counting sort cannot sort decimals, only integers, as Cary above has stated - "small, positive integers". So I'm trying to understand how I can modify this algorithm to support sorting decimals. Wouldn't radix sort support this? As it's built on counting sort?

Comment: Counting sort only works when there's a fast bi-mapping operation between any possible value being sorted and a corresponding array index. Preferably the range of the mapping is dense. Otherwise the sort will waste much memory and be slow.  For example, if you're sorting a dense collection of small integers, the mapping is the identity.  In your case, it looks like you'd need to settle for a dense set of fixed point decimals. So if there are k digits after the decimal, the mapping is m(x) = x * 10^k